# how to link java and mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I created a database from the command line and wrote Java code to access the database. My code prints an error on execution. Can anyone tell me how to connect the JDBC driver with Java?

```
import java.sql.*;

class Test{
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        try{
            String query="select * from photo ";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection
                    ("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb","user","password");
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query);
            rs.next();
            String sname=rs.getString(2); 
            System.out.println(sname);
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("error ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Try e.g. using `e.printStackTrace()` instead of `System.out.println("error ")`. For real help, you need to provide more information, like the stack trace, information regarding your database, etc.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Mysql connector is missing: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html add the library to your buildpath

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827547/java-lang-classnotfoundexceptioncom-mysql-jdbc-driver)

Comment: excuse me man, where's port of mysql ?

Comment: if exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
then it's not the problem with port .you haven't include jdbc mysql connecter.plz add it

Comment: I Downloaded connector but how should i set path

Answer (score 1):

First of all remove the space at the end of the query

```
String query="select * from photo ";
```

Next try giving the port in the url

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","user","password");
```

Finally as you said its giving you `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` 
you need to add the mysql-connector.jar in your classpath.Get the jar from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.6)

Well if you are using command prompt you can run like this

```
java -cp .;completePathOfMysqlConnector/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar className
```

If you are using elipse then download the jar and add it to the classpath like this

*Right click on the project -> properties ->java build path ->switch to libraries tab -> add external jar then select the jar and ok* you are done

Comment: Well if it worked then you can accept it as you answer so that it might help someone else to easily rectify the problem

Answer (score 0):

1>it seems that SQL port is not assigned (default is 3306) in "jdbc:mysql://localhost"
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","user","password");
2> should download and add mysql-connector-java to library
Hope this would help