# Install Mysql driver on EC2 instance?

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Unix Instance ready on Amazon EC2 .I have installed mysql in it which is runnig on 3306 port. ( Note: It is not rds database from AWS)

I have created EmpDB databse in Mysql and have created Employee table. And I have written a java program to insert a row in Table.

Below is the code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
      String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
      String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TaskDB";
      Class.forName(myDriver);
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "root");
      String query = " insert into employee (id,name,dept,salary)"
                     + " values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
      PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
      preparedStmt.setInt (1, 600);
      preparedStmt.setString (2, "Rubble");
      preparedStmt.setString(3, "startDate");
      preparedStmt.setInt(4, 5000);
      preparedStmt.execute();
      conn.close();
     } catch (Exception e){
         System.err.println("Got an exception!");
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

When I am executing it via **"java Test"**, getting below error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net
```

How I can install mysql connector on my Unix Instance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827547/java-lang-classnotfoundexceptioncom-mysql-jdbc-driver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the driver in the same folder as my `Test.java` file, and compile it, resulting in `Test.class`.

So in this folder have

```
Test.class
mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar
```

and I write this:

```
java -cp .;mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar Test
```

This way if you not use any IDE just cmd in windows or shell in linux.

Comment: java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar:. Test

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the MySql-Connector.jar into Tomcat's lib folder, and then remove the jar from the webapp's lib folder, and then, re run the project.

import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;

Comment: In my question, where do you see the web app and lib folder ??